# How to correctly convert a decimal value to exponential and exponential to decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal

I am trying decimal to exponential conversion

```
decimal Additive = 0.083333001;
string expoAdditive = string.Format("{0:#.0#E-00}",Additive);
// I got this value :8.33E-02

// exponential to decimal conversion
decimal num = decimal.Parse(expoAdditive, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
// I got this value num = 0.0833 which is wrong. I need my correct value (0.083333001)
```

Comment: Not sure what makes you think that 8.33E-02 can in any possible way be parsed into 0.83333001. Can you explain your thinking, from a mathematical point of view? Because it can't. The E-02 only indicates that you need to shift two decimal places to the left. Where did you think the 0.000033001 was getting stored, on that string?  :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide enough precision in the formatting string. Otherwise, when you parse the string to try to recover the value, it's just not there.

It's not clear from your question why you're using the format string you are. But to get the necessary 7 digits of precision to accommodate the fractional part of 8.3333001, you either need to specify 7 explicit places in your format (e.g. "{0:#.0######E-00}"), or just use the simplified formatting string of "{0:E7}".

Of course, if you have other numbers you also need to handle which have more significant digits, then you'll have to adjust the precision accordingly. Seven digits may or may not be enough for you in every case.

Comment: if i apply {0:#.0######E-00}"), or {0:E7} then it convert any number to this format it also convert decimal of value o to "0.0000000E00"
correct exponential is "0e+0"

Comment: Sorry if the suggestion doesn't work for you. Your original question is not very clear on what the actual specification here is. I'm not sure that .NET's built-in numeric formatting will do precisely what you want.  Note that if you use "+" instead of "-" in the format, then at least you'll get the "+" in the output between the "E" and the exponent.  If you really cannot tolerate the trailing 0's, you could let .NET do the initial formatting and then just strip the trailing 0's yourself.